# Extracting Part of Stream of Strings to Method

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-stream

I'm still quite new to streams and writing code in general.

I have these two methods:

Method 1:

```
private String firstMethod (String fieldAlias, String someName) {

    return Stream.of(
                    fieldAlias + ".field1",
                    fieldAlias + ".field2",
                    fieldAlias + ".field3",
                    someName + ".NAME"
            ).collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")"));
}
```

Method 2:

```
private String secondMethod (String fieldAlias, String someValue) {

    return Stream.of(
                    fieldAlias + ".field1",
                    fieldAlias + ".field2",
                    fieldAlias + ".field3",
                    someName + ".VALUE"
            ).collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")"));
}
```

This is the part I want to extract to a separate method be able to call from the stream (to avoid duplicate code):

```
fieldAlias + ".field1",
fieldAlias + ".field2",
fieldAlias + ".field3"
```

I tried creating a method  to return a list of the three strings and somehow streaming the strings from the list within the streams in the two methods. Returning the list is no problem but I just can't figure out how to incorporate the strings from that list into the existing streams. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for but your example seems to be overkill for streams or at least it could be unified by passing the 4th element completely (or if necessary pass in `someName` and `prefix`, e.g. ".NAME" or ".VALUE"). If this is just a simplified example you might need to elaborate. And if you _really_ need to use streams try returning a stream that contains the first 3 elements, then use something like `Stream.concat(first3, Stream.of(4th)).collect(....)`

Comment: The example is quite simplified. I am working on already existing code and therefore want to keep on using the streams and just outsource the part which is the same in both streams to another method. I though it would be easiest for the method to return a list of strings which than can be used within the streams. I'm not sure if I'm doing a good job at explaning, but I'll try using your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @Thomas: Using Stream.concat works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: The second method has changed the parameter name, but not the reference to it, which breaks the code. Letting this unnecessary renaming of the parameter aside, the only real difference is that `".NAME"` has changed to `".VALUE"`. If that’s really the intended only difference, make a method having that string as parameter and thus, reuse 99% of the code instead of only that inner part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, `".NAME"` or `".VALUE"` suffix may be passed within `someName` parameter.

Also, `.fieldsX` components may be extracted into a separate list, then the methods can be refactored as:

```java
private static final List<String> FIELDS = Arrays.asList(".field1", ".field2", ".field3");
private static String aliasAndParam (String fieldAlias, String param) {
    return Stream.concat(
        FIELDS.stream().map(f -> fieldAlias + f),
        Stream.of(param)
    )
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")"));
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(aliasAndParam("newField", "param.NAME")); // firstMethod
System.out.println(aliasAndParam("otherField", "p2.VALUE")); // secondMethod
```

Output:

```
(newField.field1 AND newField.field2 AND newField.field3 AND param.NAME)
(otherField.field1 AND otherField.field2 AND otherField.field3 AND p2.VALUE)
```